# How do I connect my new Raspberry Pi 4 Model B to my Laptop?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

So I got my new Raspberry pi yesterday I have been trying to connect the raspberry pi to my Laptop that has windows 10. I have been using software like puTTy but I can only get in the raspberry pi and write commands. The goal for me is to be able to have the GUI on the laptop but with the Raspian OS. So like all the features for the raspberry pi and having my Laptop as a monitor. Is there anyone that can help if yes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at VNC. RealVNC server is pre-installed on PiOS. See RPF docs at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md. Many pages on the internet available about this...

Comment: The word is [VNC](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=VNC+for+raspberry+pi&ia=web)

Comment: Or run X windows server on PC Client on PI (x windows does things differently )

Answer (score 4):

To connect to the Graphical User Interface of the Raspberry Pi you have to use **VNC**. There is a detailed instruction from the foundation how to use it. Have a look at [VNC (Virtual Network Computing)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md).

Comment: *you have to use VNC* - no, you *can* use VNC, it's ONE option, the easiest option, but by no means the only option :p

Answer (score 0):

To control your laptop from your Pi, download VNC Viewer here: https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/
(make sure you have VNC server on the laptop)

I am not entirely sure if the package architecture for your download is armhf or arm64 since you are on a Pi 4.

Actually, use this link and download the right package for arm64.
https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/linux/

Hope this helps!